Bounds on consecutive differences of the Euler totient function
Question. What bounds (in terms of $n$) do we have on the value of $|\varphi(n+1) - \varphi(n)|$? In other words, what functions $f(n)$ do we have such that
$$
|\varphi(n+1) - \varphi(n)| \le f(n)
,$$
for all $n$ (or perhaps for all sufficiently large $n$?), and what can we say about them?
Although I couldn't find much online for this exact question (I wouldn't be surprised if there were references though), there are some related results. In particular, it is known that
$$
\limsup \frac{\varphi(n + 1)}{\varphi(n)}
$$
is infinite, and one would likely expect the same for the difference, but it would be interesting to know to what order this diverging difference grows at.
An obvious trivial bound would seem to be $|\varphi(n + 1) - \varphi(n)| \le n$, but this certainly should be able to be improved upon, and there are potentially some worst case scenarios that we may look at: primes next to highly composite numbers or even Mersenne primes. Consider the latter case, letting $n = 2^p - 1$. This then transforms the difference into
$$|\varphi(2^p) - \varphi(2^p - 1)| = |2^{p-1} - 2^p + 2| = 2^{p-1} - 2 = \frac{n}{2} - \frac{3}{2}.$$
Must then $f$ be $O(n)$?
I'm not particularly familiar with analytic number theory or any such sort of powerful machinery, so I would appreciate any help, and of course any references as well would be greatly welcomed.

Where do you get your bound from ?

You only need to find positive integers $n$ such that $n+1$ is prime (then we have $\varphi(n+1)=n$) and $\varphi(n)$ is much smaller than $n$ (which is already the case if $n$ has many small prime factors with high exponents in the factorization) to confirm that we should have that $n$ is a quite shapr bound.

Perhaps the average gap is more interesting....the hope being that we thereby minimize the effect of primes being next to highly composite numbers (which, presumably, happens a lot whether or not we can prove that).

@lulu Highly composite numbers are very rare , although it could be that ifinite many have the form "prime minus one". But we do not need them to create examples where $\varphi(n)$ is very small compared to $n$. I agree your comment.

@Peter.  Right.  Should have said "numbers with many small prime factors" or something general.

@lulu Hmmm yeah the average gap does seem to be interesting and perhaps a bit easier to work with. Running a sieve algorithm and calculating the average value of $|\varphi(n + 1) - \varphi(n)| / n$ for $n$ from $1$ to $10^8$ seems to converge to a mean of around $0.406364$ with a standard deviation of $0.214707$. WolframAlpha interestingly gives that the mean is close to $4 / \pi^2$, but this could likely be a coincidence.

Interesting.  Of course, on average we expect $\varphi(n)\approx \frac {6n}{\pi^2}$ near $n$  but I don't see a sensible way to use this to get at your gap.
